# Turning off other monitors on lock screen in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, windows-8.1

In Windows 7, when the PC got locked, the lock screen appeared on the primary monitor and all other monitors connected to the PC got turned off.

(With "turning off", I don't mean turning off per se, just the state when the monitor stops recieving any signal and goes to a sleep mode or something.)

Now, on Windows 8.1 (and possibly on Windows 8 too), when the PC gets locked, the lock screen appears on the primary monitor, but the other monitors are kept running too and they show the background from the lock screen (in my case a solid color). That is a bit annoying and consumes unnecessary power.

Is there a way to make Windows 8.1 turn the other (non-primary) monitors off when the lock screen appears?

Thank you.

Comment: I do not know the answer to the question, but how about putting the PC to go to sleep after a X period of time, or just make the monitor turn off after X period of time when there is no action ?

Comment: Windows 7 does not turn the other monitors off when it's locked: the primary monitor displays the lock screen, the other monitors display solid black background. It puts all the monitors to sleep only after the specified timeout in the Power Options.

Comment: OK guys, I guess I'll set the PC to turn the monitors off a minute after locking itself for now.